# Combine two DataFrames in PySpark into matrix

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 DataFrames in PySpark script.

DF1 has this data:

```
+-----+--------------+
| id  |  keyword     |
+-----+--------------+
| 1   |  banana      |
| 2   |  apple       |
| 3   |  orange      |
+-----+--------------+
```

DF2 has this data:

```
+----+---------------+
| id | tokens        |
+----+---------------+
| 13 | ['abc', 'def']|
| 14 | ['ghi', 'jkl']|
| 15 | ['mno', 'pqr']|
+----+---------------+
```

I'm looking to build a third DataFrame by a  result of combining both of the DataFrames above and performing some complex calculations (the calculations are not important) between the keyword and the tokens defined by a python function:

```
def complex_calculation(keyword, tokens):
    // some various stuff that produces a numeric result between the keyword and the tokens
    // e.g. result = 0.7768756
    return result
```

The final result should look something like this:

```
+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
| keyword     |   13    |   14   |   15   |
+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
|  banana     |  0.5345 | 0.4325 | 0.6543 |
|  apple      |  0.2435 | 0.7865 | 0.9123 |
|  orange     |  0.3765 | 0.6942 | 0.2765 |
+-------------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Your complex calculation function is actually quite important in this context, because what you're looking to do is following:

1. Create a cartesian product of your two tables

```
table1 = spark._sc.parallelize([[1,"banana"], 
                                [2,"apple"],
                                [3,"orange"]]).toDF(["id","keyword"])

table2 = spark._sc.parallelize([[13, ['abc', 'def']], 
                                [14, ['ghi', 'jkl']],
                                [15, ['mno', 'pqr']]]).toDF(["id","token"])
```

2. Pivot with an aggregation function. Now this is where your function comes into play. As you can see, I am using `f.count()` as my aggregation function.

```
(
    table1.select("keyword")
          .crossJoin(table2)
          .groupBy('keyword')
          .pivot('id')
          .agg(f.count("token"))
).show()

+-------+---+---+---+
|keyword| 13| 14| 15|
+-------+---+---+---+
| orange|  1|  1|  1|
|  apple|  1|  1|  1|
| banana|  1|  1|  1|
+-------+---+---+---+
```

3. If you want to use some custom, clever calculation, you really have two options. If you're competent in Scala, you can write a UDAF (user-defined aggregate function) and register this jar to your Spark cluster. Alternatively, you can have a look at `pandas udfs` with something such as:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf("struct<agg_key: string, parameter1: parameter1_type>", PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_agg_function(df):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
       df.groupby(agg_key).apply(lambda x: (...))
    df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
    return df
```

And then you use your `pandas udf` such as

```
spark_df.groupBy("keyword").pivot("id").apply(my_agg_function(...)))
```

However, despite best attempts at being vectorized, `pandas udf` are still not great and can have significant performance impacts. Hope this helps. More on `pandas udf` here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf

Ideally, you should try to do your complex aggregations using spark functions as much as you can, because Tungsten can then optimise this under the hood and give you best performance possible.

Comment: The function is actually a long list of different functions, but at a higher level it comes down to a single function that receives those parameters and returns a double between 0 and 1.  I think it is too long to post it here though. I have one problem with the solution you provide, it is that this function HAS to be written in python because it uses libraries only available for python.

Comment: Will try the pandas udf method though. Thanks!